# Can you pipe ropemacs suggestions to another command?

Tags: emacs, elisp, ropemacs, pymacs, rope

is there a way of getting the completions suggestions from ropemacs' rope-code-assist (bound to "M-/" in ropemode) to use in another command?

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
(defun rope-completions-in-ido ()
    (interactive)
    (insert
        (let ((mylist ROPE-GET-COMPLETIONS-LIST))
             (ido-completing-read "Suggested Completions: " mylist))))
(define-key py-mode-map (kbd "M-/") 'rope-completions-in-ido)
```

Edit:Switched to python.el, and it magically started working, no need for the above hack. Simply calling rope-code-assist now brings up the suggestions in the minibuffer in an ido way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(As mentioned in edit) Switched to python.el, and it magically started working, no need for the above hack. Simply calling rope-code-assist now brings up the suggestions in the minibuffer in an ido way.